# How To Use InternetOpen, InternetOpenUrl and InternetReadFile

Tags: c#, .net, wininet

How I Download The WebPage Content Using winInet.dll

Code (from the comments):

```
url="http://links.casemakerlegal.com/states/TX/books/Case_Law/results?search[Cite]=359%20S.W.3d.%20856" Uri urlCheck = new Uri(url); 
WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 
wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)"); 
Stream data = wc.OpenRead(urlCheck); 
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Use `WebClient` or `HttpClient`.

Comment: I Already Used, But i'm getting "internal server error" thats why i go for wininet.dll library....

Comment: ..that is an error on the website side..

Comment: Thank you sir for your instant reply.... But if it would have been server side error then the normal browsers like Firefox must have given the  same reply... but there the link is perfectly working ... kindly help why the request from my program is rendered like this... is there anything i am missing at the security level or what else ?

Comment: How are we to know? You haven't provided any code..

Comment: my mistake sir, here is the code snippet that i have written
url="www.blahblah.com" Uri urlCheck = new Uri(url); WebClient wc = new WebClient(); wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)"); Stream data = wc.OpenRead(urlCheck); StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data); string s = reader.ReadToEnd();

Comment: @NeerajKumar:  Switching HTTP clients is guaranteed to not affect server errors.

Comment: sir can you clear little more about it ... or if you have any example..

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below. If it doesn't work.. it's definitely a server side issue:

```
string s;
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
    s = wc.DownloadString("http://www.blahblah.com"); // put your url here.
}
```

Comment: Thank u But its giving "500 - Internal Server Error"...
There is any other alternative?????

Comment: No. It's not a code issue. It is an issue with the website. Not sure how else to tell you that.

Comment: OK thank u... but because of what issue server not responding...
is there any security issue..???